# Iterate through nested class objects

Tags: javascript

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class Item {
    constructor (color, size) {
        this._color = color
        this._size = size
    }

    get color() {
        return this._color
    }
```

And I instantiate a base item:

```
const pencil = new Item('yellow', 6)
```

Then I instantiate a few sub items:

```
pencil.eraser = new Item('red', 2)
pencil.lead = new Item('grey', 1)
```

I would like to iterate through each of the sub items somehow.

```
var colors = [];

pencil.forEach(part => {
    colors.push(part.color)
}
console.log(colors) //expected output: red, grey
```

Something like that would be nice, but I know it is not possible.

Comment: [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all values of the object's properties, `.filter()` down to ones that are an `instanceof Item`, and then `.map()` them to their color.

```js
class Item {
    constructor (color, size) {
        this._color = color
        this._size = size
    }

    get color() {
        return this._color
    }
}

const pencil = new Item('yellow', 6)

pencil.eraser = new Item('red', 2)
pencil.lead = new Item('grey', 1)

var colors = Object.values(pencil)
                   .filter(v => v instanceof Item)
                   .map(p => p.color);
   
console.log(colors)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the quick answer.  I will give that a go and let you know!

Comment: That took care of it in my primary code.  Thanks.  Much better than creating an array with the names of each subitem as I go.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The for ... in loop allows you to loop through an objects properties. Then you can check whether they're instances of the Item class.

```js
class Item {
    constructor (color, size) {
        this._color = color
        this._size = size
    }

    get color() {
        return this._color
    }
}

const pencil = new Item('yellow', 6)

pencil.eraser = new Item('red', 2)
pencil.lead = new Item('grey', 1)

var colors = [];

for (let item in pencil) {
   if (pencil[item] instanceof Item) {
      colors.push(pencil[item].color);
   }
}

console.log(colors) //expected output: red, grey
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. The key that both you and Crazy Train both hit on the head is the use of instanceOf. I've definitely been preferring the imperative use of .filter() and .map() these days rather than the declarative use of for loops. Certainly thank you for your answer. I'm glad to find that there are so many ways and still use the same key needed to get there!